# event.getParam('draftValues'); returning Undefined in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components

```
 var data = event.getParam('draftValues');
    var errors = { rows: {}, table: {} };

    for(var i in data) {
        if(data[i].hours < 0 || data[i].hours > 23) {
            errors.rows[data[i].idToUpdate] = { 
                title: "We found an error.", 
                messages: ['Please select Time Slot in Between 0 to 23 Hours.'], 
                fieldNames: ['hours']
            };
        }
        if(data[i].minutes < 0 || data[i].minutes > 59) {
            errors.rows[data[i].idToUpdate] = { 
                title: "We found an error.", 
                messages: ['Please select Time Slot in Between 0 to 59 Minutes .'], 
                fieldNames: ['minutes']
            };
        }

        if(data[i].callDate < $A.localizationService.formatDate(new Date(), "YYYY-MM-DD")) {
            errors.rows[data[i].idToUpdate] = { 
                title: "We found an error.", 
                messages: ['Please select a Future Date.'], 
                fieldNames: ['callDate']
            };
        }  
    }
    if(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(errors.rows).length > 0) {
        console.log("GOT ERROR");
        errors.table.title = 'Your entry cannot be saved.';
        errors.table.messages = ['Please, Fix the errors and try again.'];
        component.set('v.errors', errors);
        console.log("component.get('v.errors')",component.get('v.errors'));
        helper.showToast("error", "Your entry cannot be saved.", "Please select Time Slot in Between 0 to 23 Hours ,  0 to 59 Minutes and Future Date.");
        return false;
    } else {
        console.log("NO ERROR");
        component.set('v.errors', '');
    }
    return true;
```

Please help me

Comment: can you post your `<ligning:datatable>` component markup and controller file?